# Function parameter which implements an interface or an extension of the interface

Tags: typescript, interface

I have the following code:

```js
interface IFoo {
  foo: string;
}

interface IFooBar extends IFoo {
  bar: string;
}

const myFun = (fooOrFooBar: IFoo) => {
  console.log(fooOrFooBar.foo);
  console.log(fooOrFooBar.bar || "I do not have bar.");
}

const myFoo: IFoo = {
  foo: "Hello",
}

const myFooBar: IFooBar = {
  foo: "Hello",
  bar: "World!",
}

myFun(myFoo);
myFun(myFooBar);
```

This would allow me to pass objects to this function which either implement `IFoo` or an extension of `IFoo`, and deal with them differently. However, the code above does not compile as `Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'IFoo'`. Is there a way to define the function so that it accepts an argument which either implements `IFoo` or any interface which extends `IFoo`?

Comment: If you know you're going to access this props upfront and they can be part of the argument, why not just type the parameter accordingly? e.g `const myFun = (fooOrFooBar: IFoo & Partial<IFooBar>) ... `

Answer (score 0):

You can use generics if you truely want to accept anything which extends `IFoo` like this:

```
const has = <K extends string>(
  key: K,
  x: object,
): x is { [key in K]: unknown } => (
  key in x
);

const myFun = <T extends IFoo>(fooOrFooBar: T) => {
  console.log(fooOrFooBar.foo);
  console.log(has('bar', fooOrFooBar) ? fooOrFooBar.bar : "I do not have bar.");
}
```

The `has` typeguard can be used to safely access any property you might want to check for.

However, if you already anticpate, that a property `bar` will be part of the object, you can also specify that in the type signature without generics:

```
const myFun = (fooOrFooBar: IFoo | IFooBar) => {
  console.log(fooOrFooBar.foo);
  console.log('bar' in fooOrFooBar ? fooOrFooBar.bar : "I do not have bar.");
}
```

This still allows to pass anything, which extends `IFoo`:

```
const x = { foo: "fsd", x: 'sdf'}
myFun(x);
```